# What does the method `WebViewClient.onReceivedLoginRequest` do

Tags: android, android-webview, webviewclient

In the [document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedLoginRequest%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) said: "Notify the host application that a request to automatically log in the user has been processed.", however, I don't understand this. Can anyone explain it in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onReceivedHttpAuthRequest` gets called for [Basic access authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). It's quite likely that your router uses this to ask you for the password if you're connecting through the web interface.

`onReceivedLoginRequest` gets called when the server sends you the `x-auto-login` header. A more detailed explanation can be found [here](http://eatdev.tumblr.com/post/40358289314/google-autologin-in-an-android-webview), for example.

Comment: Thanks, but I think `WebViewClient.onReceivedHttpAuthRequest` is the right one for handling the HTTP basic authentication.